# How to get extension file in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My code in view is like this :

```
@foreach($news as $row)
    <div class="dealprice">
        <p class="size8 red lh2">File Path: {{ $row->file_path}}</p>
    </div>                  
@endforeach
```

The result of `{{ $row->file_path}}` : assets/images/Test.pdf

I want the result : pdf

How do I get the file extension?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
@foreach($news as $row)
    <div class="dealprice">
        <p class="size8 red lh2">File Path: {{ pathinfo($row->file_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)}}</p>
    </div>                  
@endforeach
```

By passing the second parameter as `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` it will return only the file extension from the string path.